# Same variable with different types in c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a `c++` program to read a csv file. At this moment i have two functions `std::string * readdatastr()` and `double * readdatalf()` that successfully puts in a matrix the data in the file if the data is a string and if the data is a double. This function are ensembled in a class like the following:

```
class readcsv{
    public:
        int nrows;
        int ncols;
        std::string * datastr;
        double * datalf;

        void getdim(int * nrows, int * ncols){
            //function to get column and row number of the file
        }
        std::string * readdatastr(FILE * filept, int nrows, int ncols){
            //function to read data if data is std::string
        }
        double * readdatalf(FILE * filept, int nrows, int ncols){
            //function to read data if data is double
        }
        readcsv(FILE * filept, bool isstr, int nrows, int ncols){
            if(isstr){
                datastr=new std::string[nrows*ncols];
                datastr=readdatastr();
            }else{
                datalf=new double[nrows*ncols];
                datalf=readdatalf();
            }
        }
};
```

This works, but it bothers me (and afterwards it becomes a problem) that the name of the variable containing the data changes if the data is a string or a double.
Is there a way to have the two variables `datastr`,`datalf` having the same name? And if not, is there a way to have a single data matrix in the end with the right type (isstr ? std::string : double)?

Comment: Where is the variable `datalf` being used right now? Is this exactly your code?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant

Comment: @Fco, sorry there was an error at line 22-23. In any case this is not exactly my code but an example to show what i am doing.

Comment: Lots of errors in this code, for example `datastr=new std::string[nrows*ncols]; datastr=readdatastr();` If you assign to a variable twice then the value from the first assignment is lost. So `datastr=new ...` does nothing (except leak memory).

Comment: Have you tried search the internet for "C++ read csv" or "C++ read comma separated values"?  You may also want to search the internet for "C++ serialization".  Always search the internet first, as it is often faster and you get more replies.

Comment: You may find that using `std::ifstream` and `std::getline` will be more beneficial than using `FILE *` and `fscanf`.

Comment: Please edit your post with a sample of the CSV file.

Comment: there is no need for pointers or `new`. Why do the read functions return pointers? Pointers just point somewhere, to store a string you need a `std::string` not just a `std::string*`. In case you are planning to allocate everything dynamically manually, thats the wrong way.

Comment: @GiacomoMarcon *This works* -- That's like saying a car with a faulty engine and breaks can be driven.  There is a lot wrong with the code you posted -- memory leaks is just one of them.

Comment: Depending on the use case different solutions could be beneficial here: creating a template class specializations(perhaps supported by CTAD+ tag dispatch), if you only want to use an instance with the same type, a abstract base type with 2 subclasses, if you know about the type at the time of creation, but need to treat them both the same later, `std::variant`,...